# Extjs 5 multiple application with central library

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-cmd

Recently i've been exploring ExtJS 5 and making some applications with it. I've been using the Sencha CMD to generate a new application every time and the problem i see is that every application needs the whole ext framework with all the classes (which in total is 123MB, which is quite alot when you have 10+ applications).

Since there is no way for me to make 1 application with multiple subapplications (since i also have other, non-extjs, applications running on my local website), my question is rather simple: Is there a way to let all the applications use the same extjs framework build? for example in a /lib/extjs/ folder in my root?

I've looked through the sencha forum and documentation already, but i found nothing that suggests this is possible. I saw that the bootstrap.js has all the paths to the extjs framework, however if i have to manually edit all these, its going to be very time consuming..

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to the problem is to create a workspace:

```
sencha -sdk /path/to/ext generate workspace myws
cd myws
sencha -sdk ext generate app MyApp myapp
```

The above copies the library to `myws/ext` and all application in this workspace use the same copy of Ext.

Comment: Super! Accept the answer please, if it helped.

Comment: @Saki Is that true? Creating a workspace does copy the library into (e.g.) myws/ext but this is only shared for the purpose of _building_ the apps. The production build of each app _includes_ the ext library (or supposedly just those parts that are actually used by the app, though in my experience this makes little difference) in the app's aggregate js file. (Admittedly, this is based on my experience with ExtJS 6 but I don't believe much has changed in this respect since version 5.)